# Why does Doctrine MongoDB ODM always return NULL?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

I'm having trouble making this work in a fresh install

```
    /**
     * @Route("/bla")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function blaAction()
    {
        $repository = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager')->getRepository('CompanySomeBundle:User');
        $user = $repository->findOneByUsername('bla');
        var_dump($user); // NULL
        return new Response($user->getUsername()); // Fatal Error, user is not an object
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/save-bla")
     */
    public function saveBlaAction()
    {
        $user = new \Company\SomeBundle\Document\User;
        $user->setUsername('bla');
        $dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
        $dm->persist($user);
        $dm->flush();
        return new Response($user->getId()); // prints a new ID as expected, but nothing is actually saved to the DB
    }
```

I can't read data that I know is in the DB. And I can't save data either (even though I can get the new generated ID)

Note: PHP's native Mongo works just fine.

Comment: Doctrine ODM mongodb is unstable, i had some problems with it, good luck! :)

Comment: How does your User document look like?

Comment: @jules Should I use Mandango/Propel instead? But I don't like active record, I wanted to keep using Data Mapper =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem partially solved.

Changed this line: ./vendor/doctrine-mongodb/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Collection.php #146

```
--return $this->mongoCollection->batchInsert($a, $options);
++return $this->mongoCollection->batchInsert($a);
```

It was throwing a warning (batchInsert expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given9 that would stop the documents from being saved. Suppressing the warning with a @ didn't help. The problem now is that the $options argument is needed for safe writes, and I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your Mongo extension. The PHP docs state the second parameter was added in v1.0.5.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.batchinsert.php